# ASP.NET loading page timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How could I implement loading timer that are automatically appended to the each displayed page in ASP.NET and MVC?

I was thinking to implement it in Global.asax. To log the start of the request and and the end calculate a time and then smartly append it to output stream somehow. It could also be implemented in HTTP handler ...

I would like to know how to implement it in the most elegant way and to do the proper display of the result on the each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for example: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is functionality included in ASP.NET to achieve this, called [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx), or sometimes just `trace.axd`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145608/how-can-i-generate-a-complete-trace-axd-in-asp-net-mvc) for an MVC specific implementation.

> ASP.NET tracing enables you to view
>   diagnostic information about a single
>   request for an ASP.NET page. ASP.NET
>   tracing enables you to follow a page's
>   execution path, display diagnostic
>   information at run time, and debug
>   your application. ASP.NET tracing can
>   be integrated with system-level
>   tracing to provide multiple levels of
>   tracing output in distributed and
>   multi-tier applications.

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/wwh16c6c.traceaxd(en-us,VS.90).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/wwh16c6c.traceaxd(en-us,VS.90).gif)